# Real life scenario for remote file execution

Tags: web

This is a commonly demonstrated attack because it is easy to explain and understand.

The premise is that the victim does something like (oversimplified PHP example):

```
include( $_GET['file']);
```

And the attacker can pass a path to a `php` script on it's server.

My question is have you ever seen some thing like this or similar in real life code? I can't imagine what kind of requirement can cause a programmer to include a file based on user input.

Comment: I wish I could find the article but I remember reading one from a security researcher where they (somehow) managed to search through code in wordpress plugins.  They searched for instances of `system($_GET['whatever'])` (even worse then a simple remote file execution vulnerability) and had no problem finding a number of examples of such code in live plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few days ago I wrote this code:

```
$pathinfo = explode('/', $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]);
$action = $pathinfo[1];

if (ctype_lower($action) && file_exists(__DIR__ . "/$action.php")) {
    require_once __DIR__ . "/$action.php";
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not found");
    error_out("No such entrypoint");
}
```

Here I am taking the name of the action provided in the url, and load a module with that name.

You could have the same functionality with this slightly simpler condition:

```
if (file_exists("$action.php")) {
    require_once "$action.php";
}
```

which would exhibit the mentioned remote execution vulnerability (if allow_url_fopen is enabled), or even allow reading unexpected files (think on `$action = "/etc/mysecret\0"` scenarios).

(By splitting on '/' above that, it is possible that it would not work, as you would need a protocol which doesn't use a `/`. The file reading would clearly still be problematic on windows, though.)

Comment: Can you elaborate about the use case that required this solution? What is an action and what is inside the action scripts?

Comment: @Artium: this was desigining an API, I was placing the implementation of each entrypoint (the $action requested) into a different file. There are many other ways to do that, of course, like using a switch or an array to map into class names that could be then autoloaded...